# How to refresh a page in Windows8 application?

Tags: navigation, windows-8

I am wondering how I can refresh a page in a Windows8 application. I use single page navigation based on the WinJS.Navigation component.

The only way I found is to navigate on a "refresh.html" page which simply do a *WinJS.Navigation.back()* action. I am not very pleased by this solution.

I tried the *window.location.reload()* in vain.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using HTML5/JS you can just reload the data as you would when you retrieved it in the first place. I'm assuming that's an AJAX call or similar. There is no "refresh page" command or anything like that.

Comment: Indeed, an AJAX call is the correct way. In my case, it was really complex: that's why I wanted to reload it to ease my devs. But this is how I have done it finally.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a brute force way to do it. (I'm still looking for a dynamic way that doesn't require the specific page name.)

```
WinJS.Navigation.navigate("your-page-name-here.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

WinJS.Navigation know who  are you in real time with `WinJS.Navigation.location`

`WinJS.Navigation.navigate("WinJS.Navigation.location");`

Comment: This would be better suited as a comment or edit on wloescher's answer.